How to send files via bluetooth from Ubuntu to Mac OS?
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an HP computer, I would like to send a file to a Macbook, we both activated bluetooth and we are properly connected, but I have no option to actually send de file. In every tutorials I found online, they  say I should have a Send button on that screen:

I installed Blueman and it's the same, the "send file" button is greyed out. Do I miss a package or anything?
Thank you
